# Token Enumeration in Java

Tags: java, enumeration, token

I'm writing a lexer using jflex for a made up programming language.  It requires an enumeration java class which holds a bunch of tokens for the made up language.  Things like STRING_TKN, ON_TKN, GOTO_TKN, COMMAND_TKN, etc. I haven't used java in a while so I forget how to set these up.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=java+enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java as an `enum` type.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

An example:

```
public enum Colors{
    RED,BLUE,GREEN;
}
```